# Definite integral involving negative infinity

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'd really appreciate some feedback on my calculation of the definite integral below, if you could spare the time to look over my work:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{1} \frac{dx}{(3-x)^3}$$

Using the reverse chain rule:

$$f'(x) = x^{-3},\,\,\,\,f(x) = -\frac{1}{2x^2}$$
$$g(x) = 3-x,\,\,\,\,g'(x) = -1$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{1} \frac{dx}{(3-x)^3} = - \left .\left (-\frac{1}{2(3-x)^2}\right)\,\,\right |_{-\infty}^{1} = \left .\frac{1}{2(3-x)^2}\,\,\right |_{-\infty}^{1}$$

Evaluating the integral bounds:

$$=\left [\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3-1^2}\right] - \left [\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3-(-\infty)^2}\right ]$$
$$=\left [\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2} \right] - \left[\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3-\infty^2} \right]$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}-0$$
$$= \frac{1}{4}$$

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $\frac{1}{2(3-1)^2}=\frac{1}{2\cdot 2^2}=\frac 18$.

Comment: My mistake!  Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct but I used a different method. I substituted y for 3-x, evaluated the limits and calculated it from there.